# How to perform this select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have the simple table below:

```
KeyWordID   KeyWord
----------- ----------
1           Blue
3           Yellow
1           Yellow
```

How would I select the KeyWordID that selects the KeyWordIDs that where both KeyWord is Blue **and** Yellow.

E.g. it should only return 1, as this is the only KeyWordID that has **both** Keywords Blue and Yellow

I initially thought GROUPBY - but its not quite working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT KeyWordID FROM <YOUR_TABLE> WHERE KeyWord= 'Blue'
INTERSECT
SELECT KeyWordID FROM <YOUR_TABLE> WHERE KeyWord= 'Yellow'
```

Comment: I'm going to go with this answer - as INTERSECT keeps in simple. Is there any reason this shouldn't be used?

Comment: I don't know anything specific, but I was using it for a while without any issues. You can always use Explain Plan to see how the queries are performing.

Answer (score 4):

Query

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (KeyWordID INT, KeyWord VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, 'Blue')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (3, 'Yellow')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, 'Yellow')

SELECT KeyWordID FROM @TABLE
WHERE KeyWord IN ('Blue', 'Yellow') -- Keywords to find
GROUP BY KeyWordID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- Number of keyword to find
```

Result

```
KeyWordID
-----------
1
```

EDIT after jzd's comment to ignore a possible false positive:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (KeyWordID INT, KeyWord VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, 'Blue')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, 'Yellow')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (3, 'Yellow')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (3, 'Yellow')

SELECT KeyWordID FROM @TABLE
WHERE KeyWord IN ('Blue', 'Yellow') -- Keywords to find
GROUP BY KeyWordID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT KeyWord) = 2 -- Number of keyword to find
```

Comment: This works in the is case, but it there were two (1, 'Blue') rows, this would be a false positive.  Not sure if this is a true problem but the original question never said the rows were distinct.

Comment: @jzd, you're right and fortunately this is easily corrected. Edited my answer to use `COUNT(DISTINCT KeyWord)` instead of `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 3):

Join the table on to itself should do the trick:

```
SELECT a.KeywordId
FROM MyTable AS a
INNER JOIN MyTable AS b ON a.KeywordId = b.KeywordId
WHERE a.KeyWord = 'Blue'
AND b.KeyWord = 'Yellow'
```

Comment: Yea this works perfectly - However I'm a bit worried that say I had to check for a keywordID that has all of say 10 Keywords.  Thats a BIG join

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT KeywordID, COUNT(*) AS BlueAndYellow
FROM myTable
WHERE (Keyword = 'Blue' OR Keyword = 'Yellow')
GROUP BY KeywordID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Note: I haven't tried this out. But I guess this should work and give you an approach.

Comment: Yes, it works, I had the same idea and tested in before posting. You don't have to include the COUNT in the select though.